# When I add floating to a set of divs, all divs overlap and jump to the same position

Tags: css, html, css-float

I've been trying to practise building layouts for web pages and have run into a slight problem. When I try to float 1 or 2 div's, they all automatically jump to the same position and overlap. I'm sure I am missing something but I can't quite work out what it is.

Now I have 3 div's set up inside my main div for example inside "box1" I have "header", "content" & "footer".

```
<div id="box1">
<div id-"header">
    <div id="logo"><img src="logo.png"/></div>
    <div id="apology">enter text here</div>
</div>
<div id="content">
    enter content text
</div>
<div id="footer">
    footer
</div>
```

Now... It is to my knowledge (I may most probably be wrong) that when you float an object it is relative to it's container?

The two div's I am trying to float are "logo" and "apology". "logo" to the left and "apology" to make the page responsive to the size of the browser window (as you've probably guessed)

As normal the boxes stack vertically one on top of the other but as soon as I add the float properties to #logo and #apology in my CSS file, every div seems to jump to the top of the browser and overlap.

I have considered adding margins and heights to the div's in my css to position the "content" and "footer" boxes to where I want them but had deleted those entries due to it making them both fixed to where I had set the margins so when I resized the browser as normal my two floating divs would meet and arrange themselves one under the other however they would then overlap the "content" again.

I'm at the point of pulling my hair out now so any help would be much appreciated, especially as I've managed to turn a simple question into an essay.

The full html and css are below so you can test or see my errors

Many thanks, Matthew

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Welcome</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="box1">
    <div id-"header">
        <div id="logo"><img src="logo.png"/></div>
        <div id="apology">enter text here</div>
    </div>
    <div id="content">
        enter content here
    </div>
    <div id="footer">
        footer
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
#box1 {
max-width: 1024px;
border: solid black 1px;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
display:block;
-webkit-box-orient: vertical;
}
#header {
    display:block;
    -webkite-box-orient: vertical;
}
#logo {
    float: left;
    padding: none;
    display:block;
}
#apology {
    float: right;
    display:block;
}
#content {
    background:url('contentbg.jpg') center;
    background-size: cover;
    display: block;
    border: 1px black solid;
    text-align: left;
}
```

Fiddles:

[Html without CSS](http://jsfiddle.net/h9QX5)

[Html with CSS](http://jsfiddle.net/X59tp)

Comment: Might be helpful to setup a fiddle with this for us?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/h9QX5/ (without css)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/X59tp/ (with css)

Comment: I have edited my answer. Is this what you're trying to acheive?

Comment: Yes! It works! Thank you very much. I've compared the two, still unsure what that actual issue was. I must be very tired!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `display:block;`, try using `display:inline-block;`. Next is try adding a space (nbsp) to your `#header` so that the content will appear on the next line. A bit dirty but this should work. I'm still trying to figure out a way without using that `nbsp`.

[**JSBin**](http://jsbin.com/iHApamuM/1/edit)

Comment: It doesn't make a difference to any of the div's apart from putting the "content" in between my two floating objects

Thanks though

Comment: Ah I thought it might have been that. Will try it with min-height in the header to see if it can be a replacement

Comment: Not sure if you will see this but I think I've found a solution to the nbsp problem using a clearfix function and the min-height & max-height properties. Thought I would return the favour.

This is how the code now looks, try it out, works like a charm :)
[JSBin](http://jsbin.com/AmOYaWa/1/edit?html,css,output)

Answer (score 0):

You can check below updated link :

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/X59tp/1/)

```
<style>
#content {
    background:url('contentbg.jpg') center;
    background-size: cover;
    display:block;
    border: 1px black solid;
    text-align: left;
    clear:both;
}
</style>
```

Use clear in next content div check above Fiddle link..